# fast way to compute vectorized percentiles in numpy/scipy?

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy, statistics

given an array of values:

```
v = np.random.randn(100)
```

what's the fastest way to compute the percentile of each element in the array? the following is slow:

```
%timeit map(lambda e: scipy.stats.percentileofscore(v, e), v)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.stats.rankdata()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) to achieve the same result:

```
In [58]: v = np.random.randn(10)

In [59]: print(list(map(lambda e: scipy.stats.percentileofscore(v, e), v)))
[30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 90.0, 20.0, 60.0, 10.0, 70.0, 80.0, 100.0]

In [60]: from scipy.stats import rankdata

In [61]: rankdata(v)*100/len(v)
Out[61]: array([  30.,   40.,   50.,   90.,   20.,   60.,   10.,   70.,   80.,  100.])
```

Comment: Depending on your definition of percentile, you might want `(rankdata(v) - 1) / (len(v) - 1)`, which assigns the lowest value a percentile of `0`

Comment: @Eric I scaled the rank to match the result given by the code in the question, but your suggestion is also a reasonable convention.  Even just `rankdata(v)` might be sufficient--it depends on what will be done with the result.